# undefined is not an function (evaluating React.createClass)

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I want to create a simple app with react native on android. I used this source code for create Toolbar:https://rnplay.org/apps/CHOsPg
But I got this error:

```
undefined is not an function (evaluating React.createClass)
```

How can i solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Import React from `react` package, and the rest from `react-native`, like:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  ToolbarAndroid
} from 'react-native';
```

Example: https://rnplay.org/apps/nKECFw

Comment: more info https://github.com/facebook/react-native/releases/tag/v0.25.1

Answer (score 0):

Here first run the command as

```
brew install node
```

And then

```
react-native start --reset-cache
react-native run-androd
```