# undefined is not a function evaluating react create class

Tags: android, react-native

I have started learning react-native and When i am following different tutorials on net, some are using Ecma6 and other are without it. Most of the places I have read that we have a choice to use either of the syntax. But when I try to create app without ECMA6 it always gives me this error

```
undefined is not a function evaluating react create class
```

This is my code :

```
'use strict';

var React = require('react-native');

var {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  TextInput,
  View,
  Image,
  ListView
} = React;

var MyApp = React.createClass({

......

});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('MyApp', () => MyApp);
```

Am I missing something or is it not possible to use code without ECMA6 in new version of react native I am using version 0.27

Comment: relevant? : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37525984/undefined-is-not-an-function-evaluating-react-createclass/37527313#37527313

Comment: Thank you @Cherniv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

importing React from react and other component from react-native fixed the issue

```
import React from 'react';

import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  TextInput,
  View,
  Image,
  ListView
} from 'react-native';
```